# Estimating Average Marginal Effects from LASSO

Tags: predictive-models, lasso, probit

I am conducting a prediction using the LASSO probit model with a dummy on the LHS and several interacted variables on the RHS. My question is: can I meaningfully estimate the Average Marginal Effect of my individual predictors if I also use the penalised coefficients for prediction? If yes, could you please recommend ways of implementing this in Stata or R?

Currently, I am running the following in Stata:

```
lasso probit y i.X1##i.X2##c.X3 if sample==1
predict y_hat
local vars=e(allvars_sel)
probit y`vars' if sample==1
margin, dydx(*) post
```

But I am not sure if this is correct given that the second probit estimation doesn't use the penalised coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by *the second probit estimation*? Do you have two versions of your model, one penalized and another nonpenalized? Could you not focus on just one version that you are interested in?

Comment: Thank you for your message @RichardHardy! When I mentioned the second version, I was referring to the line 4 of the Stata code, where I am regressing the variables selected by LASSO on the outcome variable. I am using this because Stata allows me to estimate marginal effects after the 'probit' command, while it does not allow this after the 'lasso probit' command.

Comment: My conceptual worry about this however is that when I am regressing only the selected coefficients on the outcome, my estimates will be different than what the penalised lasso estimates, and so the AME do not correspond exactly to what I want it to. I prefer using the penalised coefficients for prediction as my results appear more meaningful with that.

Comment: It seems Stata turns out to be less than ideal in this situation. Given the estimated LASSO probit model, could you perhaps try obtaining the AME analytically?

Comment: I'm afraid that would be quite complicated as there are many interacted variables on the RHS, and I would have to average over all of their values.